# Fabric chaincode ABAC is not working once after identity attribute update

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am using fabric [cid](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid) for chaincode ABAC. It works fine; however once after updating the identity attribute (through node sdk) the ABAC did not work as intended.

My Workflow:

1.Register and enroll identity through node SDK.

> Ex value,
>
> attrs: [ {"name": "role", "value": "client", "ecert": true} ]

2.Chaincode invoke. ABAC works as intended.

> identity, err := cid.New(stub)
>
> err = identity.AssertAttributeValue("role", "client")

3. Update identity attribute (role -> user)

> Ex value,
>
> attrs: [ {"name": "role", "value": "user", "ecert": true} ]

4. Chaincode invoke. ABAC error with same condition.

When I logged the attribute, i found that the identity still carries the old role (client) instead of updated value (user); however the **fabric-ca-server.db** users table has the latest attribute value (user). little confused here!!

Am I missing any steps? Could anyone help me to find out the exact cause for this?

**Edit:**

Fabric v1.4

Comment: I assume you re-enrolled the user to "pull down" the new certificate with updated attribute?

Comment: @RThatcher,  no; I did the following
**Identity update**: identityService.update
**Remove identity**: identityService.delete -> wallet.delete....   

In btw, could you please tell me the flow for update and remove identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My example workflow below used the fabric-ca-client binary CLI - not client code.  But I did use the cid object in my chaincode/smart contract.

When you **Register** an ID an entry is created in the CA database.

When you **Enroll** an ID the certificate and key are downloaded - if you include the ecert flag then the attribute is included in the certificate.

If you **modify** an ID the entry in the CA database.  (But the certificate still has the old value)

When you **reenroll** the ID the certificate is replaced and the new certificate contains the new modified attribute value.  When you use connect to the chaincode with the new certificate the **cid** object will show the new value.